# Python Windows Authentication username and password is not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-authentication, basic-authentication

I am trying to enter data in prompt (URL Given), below codes is giving me an error. Please help me out with these?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.authenticate('admin','admin')
time.sleep(4)
alert.accept()
```

I have tried with:

```
ActionChains(driver).send_keys("admin").send_keys(Keys.TAB).send_keys("admin").perform()
```

This one is also not working.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem but the first thing I see is you forgot the "()" in alert = driver.switch_to.alert()

Comment: tried : `alert = driver.switch_to.alert()
TypeError: 'Alert' object is not callable`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you work with **`Selenium 3.4.0`**, **`geckodriver v0.18.0`**, **`Mozilla Firefox 53.0`** through **`Python 3.6.1`** you can bypass the **`Basic Authentication`** popup through embedding the `username` and `password` in the `url` itself as follows.

This solution opens the `URL` **http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth** and authenticates with a valid `username` and `password` credentials.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")
```

Comment: FWIW: embedded credentials will only partially work using chrome v59+ because sub-resource requests will be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

```
    def test_1_authentication(self):
        self.driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")
        shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
        shell.Sendkeys("admin")
        time.sleep(3)
        shell.Sendkeys("{TAB}")
        time.sleep(3)
        shell.Sendkeys("admin")
        time.sleep(3)
        shell.Sendkeys("{ENTER}")
        time.sleep(3)
```

Above code is also properly worked :)

Comment: Is the above code working now? I found the same piece of code which was working well for me is not working now. I asked question about the same here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491048/windows-authentication-code-no-longer-working-now

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `PyAutoGui`:

```
pip3 install pyautogui
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pyautogui


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("htt`enter code here`p://95.141.198.238/noload2/files/074/UTF- 
RSLOAD.NET-.zip")

pyautogui.write('rsload.net') # login
pyautogui.press('tab')        # Tab
pyautogui.write('rsload.net') # pass
pyautogui.press('enter')      # Enter
```