# Handle required authentication using Chrome 60 with Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**My problem:**

Currently I need to open a site where I need to put user and password in the chrome authentication window, but I'm trying the only alternative I found on the internet, but without success

[image]

**I tried this:**

```
https://myuser:mypassword@mysite.com
```

but this is not solving because in this format the website is not opening, much less authenticating with the credentials in the url

**my stack:**

Python 3 + Selenium 3.3.3 + Chrome 60

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium Alert - Prompt username & password is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328654/python-selenium-alert-prompt-username-password-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Idk about python but in c# you can handle it as follows;

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("username", "password");
alert.Accept();
```

Comment: My above image is not an alert. This option dont solved for me

Answer (score -1):

You might need to use a plugin, like I had to.
This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629531/how-to-pass-pass-user-credentials-to-chrome-via-native-messaging-api/47629532) details how I solved the problem in Chromium/Chrome ...

## Solution:

**This was implemented in python 2.7**
But there shouldn't be too much difference to make it work in 3.X

You're going to need to use a browser extension.
My solution has been built for chromium but it should port almost-unchanged for Firefox and *maybe* edge.

**First** up, you need 2 APIs to be available for your browser:

- `webRequest.onAuthRequired` - [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) & [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onAuthRequired)
- `runtime.nativeMessaging` - [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging) & [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendNativeMessage)

While both browser APIs are very similar, they do have some significant differences - such as Chrome's implementation lacking [Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks).

If you setup your Native Messaging Host to send a properly-formed JSON string, you need only poll it once. This means you can use a single call to `runtime.sendNativeMessage()` and be assured that your credentials are paresable. Pun intended.

**Next**, we need to look at how we're supposed to handle the `webRequest.onAuthRequired` event.

Since I'm working in Chromium, I need to use the promise-less Chrome API.

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
  callbackFunctionHere,
  {urls:[targetUrls]},
  ['asyncBlocking'] // --> this line is important, too. Very.
```

## The Change:

I'll be calling my function `provideCredentials` because I'm a big stealy-stealer and used an example from [this](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/JavaScript.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/WebRequest/onAuthRequired.html#Examples) source. Look for the asynchronous version.

The example code fetches the credentials from `storage.local` ...

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, gotCredentials);
```

We don't want that. Nope.

We want to get the credentials from a single call to `sendNativeMessage` so we'll change that one line.

```
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(hostName, { text: "Ready" }, gotCredentials);
```

That's all it takes. Seriously. As long as your Host plays nice, this is the big secret. I won't even tell you how long it took me to find it!

## Links:

My questions with helpful links:

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47029113/workaround-for-python-selenium-authenticate-against-active-directory) - Workaround for Authenticating against Active Directory
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564226/javascript-syncronicity-combining-onauthrequired-listener-and-native-massaging) - Also has some working code for a functional NM Host
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605439/how-to-get-values-out-of-promises) - Some enlightening material on promises