# Push username & password to alert using Selenium python 3+

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

[Alert on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgSqH.png)

Hi Everyone
i am trying to accept alert using below code but i am getting timeout exception everytime. tried increasing wait time still same error

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get('abc.com')
alert = wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())  ----------Error at this line
time.sleep(4)
#WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.send_keys('username' + Keys.TAB + 'password')
alert.accept()
```

Error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav Chhabra\Desktop\FAIL_RATE.py", line 30, in <module>
    alert = wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav Chhabra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

What could be the reason as  have used the same code on another website and its working, is this is because of some website features which are unable etc ?
i have also attached image of alert

or if somebody can help me with some new way to pass username & password in this alert ?

thanks

Comment: Are you this is an alert and not a modal dialog?

Comment: no idea on that part.... is there a way if i can check that ?

Comment: Right click on the popup in your browser, inspect it and see if it is a HTML element or something else.

Comment: oh in that way...well its not a model as i a unable to inspect it

Comment: As you are unable to inspect the element it seems to be the Basic Authentication dialog box and a possible duplicate of [Python Selenium Alert - Prompt username & password is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328654/python-selenium-alert-prompt-username-password-is-not-working)

Comment: correct it is a basic authetication ..thank you very much