# Send keys are not working in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login a webpage using Selenium webdriver in Google Chrome. The input box pop ups for login credentials don't have any ID or class. Inspect element features itself not there when I right click on the input box. When I click F12 and check the elements, the input box is not highlighted which means the input box is not part of html content.

When I load the URL, by default the focus goes to username box. So I wanted to use send_keys but this is not working without elements. Is there any other alternate method to send text to username & password fields?

Below is the code I tried.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.somewebsite.com/')
time.sleep(15)
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.send_keys('userxxxxx').perform()
action.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
action.send_keys('pwdxxxxx')
action.send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Attached the screenshot of right click and elements.

[image]

When I execute the above code, no error messages. It steps through the further line of codes.

How can I fix this?

Comment: There is no need to ActionChains and perform for Send Keys in python. You can just directly use SendKeys. I also see there are no elements you have located. Then I saw your image, and thought this might of help. [Check This Out - similar SO query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I removed actionchains and used SendKeys directly. I am getting below error message.
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'Send_Keys'. Seems send keys can be used on some element not on the driver :(

Comment: driver.get("https://admin:admin@your website url"); this one also didnt work for my URL

Comment: Try this. If it is an alert box, this may work (although the first method should be more reliable)
`al = driver.switch_to.alert \n
al.send_keys(keysToSend="username" + Keys.TAB + "password")  \n
al.accept()`

The `\n` is added to indicate it's a line break (for you). You have to click Enter at each `\n`  (and remove `\n` from code)

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297014/5226491

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not an alert box too. Thanks for your suggestion. will check the above link.