# How to pass special character in URL in windows authentication?

Tags: python, selenium

To handle windows authentication, one way to handle such scenario is by passing credentials in URL itself as shown below

```
driver.get('http://username:password@abc.com')
```

But in my case since password contains special character, like 'password@123', so now code contains double special character '@' as shown below

```
driver.get('http://username:password@123@abc.com')
```

I tried replacing '@' with '%40' using url encoder/decoder, but it's not working. I am working with python selenium, any idea how to handle such scenario?

Comment: did you try backslash, it's the usual Python escape character

Comment: You meant to say something like this password/@123?

Comment: AFAIK, `http://username:password@abc.com` approach doesn't work in last browser versions...

Comment: that's a forward slash, like this password\@123

Comment: @Calculus, It shows exception selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:....."Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}

Comment: @Andersson, I tried below example on my machine and it worked with url provided there as credential does not contain special character there, but in my case credential contains special character, so I am assuming if I can handle this then it should work with my application url as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328654/python-windows-authentication-username-and-password-is-not-working/45329228#45329228

Comment: If it doesn't work with `"https://%s:%s@%s/" % (quote('my username'), quote('my passord'), "abc.com")` then it's either not a [`Basic Authentication`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), or the page is redirected.

Comment: It shows window authentication same as on click on this url -> https://www.engprod-charter.net/ <-- but there is one difference on click of url says abc.com when windows authentication popup appears, url changes say xyz.com. Now I tried to pass credential with both of these url separately. When the password contains special character, it does not work, but if password does not contain any special character it works with second url xyz.com which appears while windows authentication popup is displayed.

Comment: from you last comment, the domain is redirected to `https://www.engprod-spectrum.net/`. You need to authenticate on the landing domain without any path in the URL. An other way would be to use an extension: https://gist.github.com/florentbr/25246cd9337cebc07e2bbb0b9bf0de46

Comment: Could you please explain what do you meant by this "without any path in the URL"... In my case a very long URL is displayed on landing page like https://...new_url.org/adfs/ls/wia?SAMLRequest=lZLLTsMwEEX3fEXkfd5pCVaTKrRCVCpQtSkLNshJJq0lxw4ep4W%2FJ%2FSByqYS%2B3vPjM94NP...........

Comment: Regarding using chrome extension, need to check how it can be done in python selenium as I am working with python. https://gist.github.com/florentbr/25246cd9337cebc07e2bbb0b9bf0de46

Comment: For an URL defined as `scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]`, Chrome will ignore the credentials if the URL contains a path or a query.

Comment: Getting this issue, "Cannot navigate to invalid URL". Seems some problem in arranging data here host[:port]][/path][?query] or issue with parenthesis, trying to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple **raw** **string** will do the job, ***note*** that I use triple quotes just for escaping any possible errors with `'` and `"`.

```
driver.get(r'''http://username:password@123@abc.com''')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try out with the below syntax:

```
String url =  http://username:password%40123@abc.com;
driver.get(url);
```

In one of the application, we have more than one @ character in the password. I'm simply escaping the @ character. For example

```
URL: http://username:password@#@@sample.com
Encoded_URL:  http://username:password%40%23%40@sample.com
```

and then try to browse the encoded URL.

```
driver.get(Encoded_URL);
```

For me, it is working fine. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I applied this, it seems to be loading application infinitely without entering credential. My password is something like "Abc@123". So it should be like "http://username:Abc@123%40123@abc.com"?

Comment: So that means now you are not getting `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:....."Cannot navigate to invalid URL` error now that you were facing earlier. So if you are not getting any error and page is getting loaded that means the problem is with server-side during authentication. Server is taking time to authenticate the request.

And one more thing, if your password is `Abc@123` so the URL would be `username:Abc%40123@abc.com`. Don't forget to add protocol scheme ie `http/https`.

Comment: And if you are not able to see the credentials that are the behavior of the browsers due to security reasons, a user can not see the credentials while making the request.

Comment: That I have already tried, replacing @ in password with %40 which I mentioned in last line in my question itself, it is not working.

Comment: It seems to me I need to to decode url here.... driver.get(decode_fun(Encoded_URL)), need to check the function in python to perform it

Answer (score 0):

If your username is 'shoaib' and your password is `akhtar@123` then your `.get()` invocation should be:

```
driver.get('http://shoaib:akhtar%40123@abc.com')
```