# Python urlparse failed if =? exists in the password

Tags: python

When using Python `urlparse` on this URL i get this error

```
urlparse("https://a:=?@1.2.3.4:123").port
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-4f5e20527e52> in <module>
----> 1 urlparse("https://a:=?@1.2.3.4:123").port

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/urllib/parse.py in port(self)
    167         port = self._hostinfo[1]
    168         if port is not None:
--> 169             port = int(port, 10)
    170             if not ( 0 <= port <= 65535):
    171                 raise ValueError("Port out of range 0-65535")

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '='
```

Is `=?` not legal chars in the basic password or is the `urlparse` implementation incorrect?

Comment: Isn't it the first `:` that is messing up the parsing? The parser is trying to parse `=?@1.2.3.4:123` as a port.

Comment: The `?` indicated the beginning of a query string in the URL. You should URL-encode it: `%hex_value`.

Comment: @khelwood the `:` is for the `user:pass` format.

Comment: @KlausD. I have all the URL as a string, should I encode all of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass special character in URL in windows authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899423/how-to-pass-special-character-in-url-in-windows-authentication)

Answer (score 2):

If the user and password field contain any `":"`, `"@`", or `"/"` characters, that must be encoded. See the explanation in [*rfc1738*(Common Internet Scheme Syntax)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#section-3.1)

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>>
>>> r = urllib.parse.urlparse("https://a:=%3F@1.2.3.4:123")
>>> print(r)
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='a:=%3F@1.2.3.4:123', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> print(r.port)
123
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in my example, the password does not contain any of ":" "@" or "/", it seems that the "?" in the password causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the user/pass as part of the url will not work in most of the major browsers (FF, Safari, IE, Chrome etc).

The reason for that is that it's *not secure* to pass credentials as clear-text (part of the URL).

For more reading see section [4.1 of this RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt)

You may also be interested in reading the following:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/browsers/name-and-password-not-supported-in-website-address
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82250#c7
- [How to pass special character in URL in windows authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899423/how-to-pass-special-character-in-url-in-windows-authentication)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters#