# Python Selenium with Windows Security Pop up

Tags: python, selenium

I am relatively new with Selenium but I am not sure if this is possible. The current site I need to get into needs authentication. My issue is that the authentication for site is not in the form of another webpage it is what I believe is a windows popup and I have no clue how I can write code to access this security box so I can fill in credentials automatically in script to login.

This is the box

[image]

Once I run selenium and get to this box the edge browser is completely frozen and inaccessible until this authentication is done and we go back to browser. When this is up I can see the debug mode show the html with empty body. Any idea how I can get into this box and fill in required to continue with seleniumm or other tool if required.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45329228/7429447) answers your question?

Comment: Wow close but for some reason when it goes to the box it does not activate user field the first field done is the password. without user name so it fails. Any way to activate username field on at first open?

Comment: I guess the  more correct way to say it is once the alert opens the alert focus is not on the user name so the username keystrokes go no where